# How to redirect to frontend login page in react after account activation via email sent by Djoser in django and drf

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am in the process of implementing Djoser into my current project.
On the front end I have a form for registration, onSubmit and onSuccess redirect to a page telling the user to check their email and click the activation link. This link and email are sent by Djoser. The email now prints in the console and it looks like this:

```
<p>Please go to the following page to activate account:</p>
<p><a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/OQ/bnjmpy-22a214344550a46e302c11411567af4e">http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/OQ/bnjmpy-22a214344550a46e302c11411567af4e</a></p> 

<p>Thanks for using our site!</p>
```

After clicking on this link, I am of course taken to the browser, to the exact link where the DRF page is displayed in the browser. I want to display the Login page in React instead.

I was thinking of redirecting from the backend to the frontend and there wywowalać getrequest to the activation link, or somehow in APIView redirect to the frontend login page. However, I don't know how to do that and can't find info on how to solve it.

```
DJOSER = {
   'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
   'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
   'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
   'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
   'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
   'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
   'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
   'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
   'SERIALIZERS': {
        "user_create": "accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer",  # custom serializer
        "user": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "current_user": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
        "user_delete": "djoser.serializers.UserSerializer",
   }
}
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('activate/<str:uid>/<str:token>/', UserActivationView.as_view()),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path("auth/", include("djoser.urls.jwt")),
]
```

```
class UserActivationView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny,]

    def get(self, request, uid, token):
        post_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/activation/"
        post_data = {"uid": uid, "token": token}
        result = requests.post(post_url, data=post_data)
        content = result.text
        return Response(content)
```